# App Store versionning rules for watchOS apps

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-watch, watchos

I have a watchOS app and it’s iOS counterpart in the AppStore.
For now, my app support iOS 15 and watchOS 8.

The next version will make a huge step forward and supports iOS 17 and watchOS 10.

I have a question :

If someone has an iPhone on iOS17 and a watch on watchOS 8, will the AppStore update the app ?

It will be incompatible as the new iOS app won’t work with the old watchOS one.

I hope the AppStore won’t propose the update in this case to avoid impacting users with a modern iPhone and an old Apple Watch who can continue with the previous app version.
What’s your advice ?

Comment: I would imagine that the iOS app update would be available and once updated the watch app would no longer be available to that user.

Comment: I hope it's not the case ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking on real devices: iPhone on iOS17 and Apple Watch run-in watchOS 9, I have verified that App Store don't install the new version if both minimum OS requirements are not met.
So it's handled perfectly well.